# GeoServer 2.15: "REST PathMapper Root directory path" ignored?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to create stores in my GeoServer setup through the REST API and try to force the store creation to take place in a specific directory by setting the "REST PathMapper Root directory path" under Settings > Global > REST PathMapper Root directory path.
But the stores are still created under the default location: $GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/data.

I do not see any error message in the log files (most detailed verbosity level).

Has anyone experience with setting REST PathMapper Root directory path?

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but for my specific case I found a way around it: Now I prepare all files on the location where I want them (data granules and *.properties files) and then use the REST API while indicating the file location as an external mosaic store: curl -v -u admin:password -XPUT -H "Content-type:text/plain" -d "file://{[path_to_data}" "https://{server}/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores/{store}/external.imagemosaic"